# Leaflet marker/icon help

Tags: leaflet, markers, nominatim, icon

I am trying to get the default marker NOT to show, but it's coming up WITH the icon that I want, so I have a marker and icon like this:

[image]

I'm getting my data from a OSM nomination search result.

```js
if (response) {
        var mArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var result = response[i];
            var s = result.display_name;
            var ex = result.extratags;
            var lk = ex.website;
            var ph = ex.phone;
            var hr = ex.opening_hours;
            var poly = result.geojson;
            if (hr) {
                var hours = hr.replace(/\;/g, '<br/>');
            }
            var arr = s.split(', ');
            var dd = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(", "));
            var cc = dd.substring(dd.indexOf(",") + 1);
            var rIcon = result.icon;
            var myIcon;
            if (rIcon) {
                myIcon = new L.Icon({
                    iconSize: [35, 35],
                    iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                    popupAnchor: [1, -24],
                    iconUrl: rIcon
                });
            } else if (!(rIcon)) {
                myIcon = new L.Icon({
                    iconSize: [35, 35],
                    iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                    popupAnchor: [1, -24],
                    iconUrl: 'lib/images/question.png'
                });
            }
            var srchPops = "<div class=\"mypopupinfo\">";
            srchPops += "<div class='popHeader'><h6><strong>" + arr[0] + "</strong></div>";
            srchPops += "<div class='popBody'><h6>" + cc +
                    "</h6></div>";
            srchPops += "<button class='btn btn-default btn-xs add-field' value='" + result.lat + ", " + result.lon + "'>Add Point</button>";
            srchMarkers = new L.marker([result.lat, result.lon], {icon: myIcon}).bindPopup(srchPops);
            srchPoly = L.geoJson(poly);
            mArray.push(srchMarkers, srchPoly);
        }
    }
    srchresultMarkers = L.layerGroup(mArray);
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks strange that you add both a GeoJSON layer from `result.geojson` and a marker created from `[result.lat, result.lon]`.

If `result.geojson` contains the same point information as `[result.lat, result.lon]`, you are adding both markers to your map.

Comment: That's correct.  I figured that out myself about 45 mins ago.  :)

Comment: Good job in finding it out by yourself! :-)

Answer (score 2):

an event listener and change the icon through setIcon() method:

```
createdMarker.on("dblclick", function(evt) {

        var myIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'res/marker-icon-red.png',
            shadowUrl: 'res/marker-shadow.png'
        });
        this.setIcon(myIcon);
});
```

Or you can get some help from this [Tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html)